# Estimated time minus spent time wrong result - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, left-join

I have tasks that are estimated to some hours. And time spent minus estimated should result in time left to spend.

Employee table

```
CREATE TABLE sign
    (signid varchar(3), signname varchar(30));    
INSERT INTO sign
    (signid, signname)
VALUES
    ('AA', 'Adam'),
    ('BB', 'Bert'),
    ('CC', 'Cecil'),
    ('DD', 'David')
```

Task table

```
CREATE TABLE task
    (taskid int4, taskdate date, tasksign varchar(3), taskhr numeric(10,2));

INSERT INTO task
    (taskid, taskdate, tasksign, taskhr)
VALUES
    (1,'2016-01-01','AA',10),
    (2,'2016-02-01','BB',10),
    (3,'2016-01-15','BB',10),
    (4,'2016-03-01','BB',10),
    (5,'2016-01-03','CC',10)
```

Time sheet table

```
CREATE TABLE hr
    (hrid int4, hrsign varchar(3), hrtask int4, hrqty numeric(10,2));

INSERT INTO hr
    (hrid, hrsign, hrtask, hrqty)
VALUES
    (1,'AA',1,1.1),
    (2,'BB',2,1.2),
    (3,'CC',5,2.3),
    (4,'CC',5,5)
```

My attempt to get a simple query that subtract spent time from estimated time gives wrong answer:

```
SELECT    signid,signname,to_char(taskdate, 'iyyy-iw'),sum(taskhr),sum(hrqty)
FROM      sign
LEFT JOIN task ON tasksign=signid
LEFT JOIN hr ON taskid=hrtask
GROUP BY  1,2,3
ORDER BY  2,3
```

The answer is:

```
id  name    week     task   hr
AA  Adam    2015-53  10     1,1000
BB  Bert    2016-02  10     NULL
BB  Bert    2016-05  10     1,2000
BB  Bert    2016-09  10     NULL
CC  Cecil   2015-53  20     7,3000
DD  David   NULL     NULL   NULL
```

The task hours seems to be duplicated. It should look like this:

```
id  name    week     task   hr
AA  Adam    2015-53  10     1,1000
BB  Bert    2016-02  10     NULL
BB  Bert    2016-05  10     1,2000
BB  Bert    2016-09  10     NULL
CC  Cecil   2015-53  10     7,3000
DD  David   NULL     NULL   NULL
```

Any tip how to make a query that calculate correct?

"fiddle"

http://rextester.com/UOO16020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joining the `hr` table multiplies the `task` table rows. Aggregate `hr` before joining:

```
select signid, signname, to_char(taskdate, 'iyyy-iw'), sum(taskhr), sum(hrqty)
from
    sign
    left join
    task on tasksign = signid
    left join (
        select hrtask, sum(hrqty) as hrqty
        from hr
        group by 1
    )
    hr on taskid = hrtask
group by  1,2,3
order by  2,3
;
 signid | signname | to_char |  sum  | sum  
--------+----------+---------+-------+------
 AA     | Adam     | 2015-53 | 10.00 | 1.10
 BB     | Bert     | 2016-02 | 10.00 |     
 BB     | Bert     | 2016-05 | 10.00 | 1.20
 BB     | Bert     | 2016-09 | 10.00 |     
 CC     | Cecil    | 2015-53 | 10.00 | 7.30
 DD     | David    |         |       |
```

Comment: Thank you! Right on target.